# Differential correction wizard doesn't pop up?

Tags: gps, trimble, pathfinder

Any Trimble GPS Pathfinder Office users out there ever run into this problem? When I try to run the differential correction wizard the program stutters for a brief second then nothing happens. All other utilities (data transfer, export, etc.) still work fine.

Also, if I decide I need to reinstall the program does anyone know if I have to deactivate my single use license beforehand?

Comment: has the differential correction wizard ever worked?

Comment: Yes it had. Not sure what the problem was that caused it to not 'pop up' but it has been fixed with an upgrade in PFO software/license necessary to run a new GPS unit.

Answer (score 1):

I realise you have solved the problem by updating PFO, but in case anyone else has the same problem, I can answer the second part of the question.

It is not necessary to uninstall the single-use license if you want to re-install PFO on the same PC.  The Trimble license servers use some hash value derived from your PC hardware when you register a license, so they allow you to reinstall the same PFO version (or one with the same license date) on the same PC.

I can't suggest what would have caused the original problem, but a PFO reinstall would probably have fixed it.